# "as she did X" vs "while she did X"

Tags: word-usage, time

Another question related to correctly conveying a sense of time:

> Who will be held accountable for the costs incurred **as** the managers dragged their feet?

vs

> Who will be held accountable for the costs incurred **while** the managers dragged their feet?

Are both of these correct? "As" sounds better to me, but I am not a native speaker.

Comment: I recommend using *when* instead.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, but I would be more inclined to use 'while' as it indicates that time is passing *while* the managers are dragging their feet.

Answer (score 1):

While sounds better to me, although I think you could say either without much argument.  As can have the meaning of either while or because, so is perhaps less precise.

I would probably say "Who will be held accountable for the costs incurred while the managers **were dragging** their feet?"